# We have legs but can never stand alone

Tags: riddle, word

One we are, a pair are we. We have legs but can never stand alone. What am I?

5 letters

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 3):

Looks too simple but could it be

> Pants

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.